# EmEditorで正規表現の大量行を通すと起こる現象

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
WEB APIに接続する直前に正規表現の数万行のマクロを通すと異常に重くなります。
フリーズしたような状態に陥ってWEB APIのところで止まるのですが、原因は何が考えられますでしょうか？

この現象は正規表現のコードをなくして単なる置換のみにしたり、マクロの行を減らすか、このマクロのインクルードを外してテストすると解消してサクサク状態になります。
画像は重くなる現象の直前の終了部分になります。
現在のテスト段階ではこれが一番多い行になります。
EmEditorは最新です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 検索文字列の強調表示が遅くなっている可能性があるため、`ツール` メニューの `すべての設定のプロパティ` の `表示` ページで、`検索色` を 0 にして、問題が改善するかお試しください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。複数回、設定を変えるのと元に戻すのをやりましたら、まさに指摘頂いたことが原因だったようです。変えるとサクサクに戻りました。これは、工程の多いマクロのときは自動的にオンオフになるようにマクロで記述できるのか、EmEditor側で工程が多いマクロでは自動的に変更できるようにしていただけませんでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 正規表現やマクロの行数は変えずにマクロファイル側で可能な対策はありますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マクロの最初に `Redraw = false;` と記述してみてはいかがでしょうか?

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ある程度の解決になりました。動作自体はしてました。ただ、まだ完全な解決ではない状態でして、画像の数万行のマクロはRedraw = false;で描画の動きを止めて、次のインクルードマクロから描画を再開でRedraw = false;にすると画面がフリーズしたようになります。次のインクルードマクロもRedraw = false;で描画じたいを全部止めてしまえば何も動かなくなってもファイル自体は作成されているようです。検索の色を0にするとこの問題は解決しますが、普段の検索で色が付かないという副作用が起きます。理想の解決は、重たい数万のマクロだけを描画オフにして、それ以降で動くマクロは通常どおり描画を再開にして検索の色もつくということは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 全部一律の変更ではなく、一定の負荷がかかる行数や量になった場合のみ、内部でオンオフを変更するというしくみならありがたいです。

Comment: WEB APIじたいは、もともと単独では描画も動作もサクサクでしたが、数万行マクロの直後にやると描画がおかしくなるようです。

Comment: WEB API というのは何を行っているのでしょうか? `Redraw = false;` で編集した後、`Redraw = true;` を実行すれば再描画が行われます。一定の負荷がかかる行数や量になった場合のみ、内部でオンオフを変更するというしくみは検討したいと思います。

Comment: マクロを実行中だけ、検索色を 0 にする方法もあったので、回答でまとめます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。この現象の報告が他の人からはまだ来てないようでしたら、私の処理はかなり重い処理だと思います。さらに文字に正規表現のメタ文字を追加していって1回の対象文章を30万字くらいでやっていますが、上記の対策をしてからは順調です。

Answer (score 0):

多数の複雑な正規表現を使用した連続検索/置換の後は、検索文字列の強調表示が著しく遅くなっている可能性があります。そのため、その後の動作が遅く感じられることがあります。その対処方法として、次の方法が考えられます。

1. 連続置換は、なるべく正規表現を使用せず、置換数を減らして、できるだけシンプルにしてみてください。
2. `ツール` メニューの `すべての設定のプロパティ` の `表示` ページで、`検索色` を `0` にします。
3. マクロを実行中だけ、検索色を 0 にしたい場合には、以下の3行をマクロの最初で実行します。

```
cfg = document.Config;
cfg.Display.SearchColors = 0;
cfg.Save();
```

さらに、以下の3行をマクロの最後で実行します。

```
cfg = document.Config;
cfg.Display.SearchColors = 1;
cfg.Save();
```

ただし、マクロがエラーのために途中で中断された場合には、自動的には元に戻りません。

4. マクロの最初に `Redraw = false;` と記述します。再描画が必要なタイミングでは、`Redraw = true;` と記述することにより、必要な時だけ再描画されます。マクロが終了すると、自動的に `Redraw = true;` を実行するのと同様に再描画されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。出来ました。御厚意､感謝しております。他のことも現在確認しておりまして順調です。